# Implementing filter feature in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I am trying to implement a filter feature in my angular application.

In my page, I have subscribed to changes in the filter component and as soon as user makes any change I want to filter the result set and display the matching data.

I have a property to maintain the filter values like this

`selectedFilters = { "brand" : ["a", "b"], "category": ["x"], "materialType": [1, 2, 3] }`

whenever the filter gets updated I have the following logic to do the filter

```
result = { "set1" : [{"brand": "a", "category": "x", "materialType": 1},{"brand": "a", "category": "y", "materialType": 2}], "set2": [{"brand": "a", "category": "x", "materialType": 1},{"brand": "b", "category": "z", "materialType": 3}]}

let filteredSet1, filteredSet2;

if (selectedFilters.brand.length > 0) {
    filteredSet1 = result.set1.filter((item) => selectedFilters.brand.includes(item.brand))

    filteredSet2 = result.set2.filter((item) => selectedFilters.brand.includes(item.brand))
} else {
    filteredSet1 = result.set1;
    filteredSet2 = result.set2;
}

if (selectedFilters.category.length > 0) {
    filteredSet1 = filteredSet1.set1.filter((item) => selectedFilters.category.includes(item.category))

    filteredSet2 = filteredSet2.set2.filter((item) => selectedFilters.category.includes(item.category))
} 

if (selectedFilters.materialType.length > 0 ) {
    filteredSet1 = filteredSet1.set1.filter((item) => selectedFilters.materialType.includes(item.materialType))

    filteredSet2 = filteredSet2.set2.filter((item) => selectedFilters.materialType.includes(item.materialType))
} 


const finalResult = {set1: filteredSet1, set2: filteredSet2};
```

I am not sure if this is a good approach to do this, but if someone could provide a better option would be happy to try that too.

Thanks

Comment: I would strongly suggest better variable names `filter1`, `filter2`, and `filter3` and all the other variables that just have numbers after them are not descriptive at all. It's hard to suggest a way to improve the code because nothing has any meaning unless you are familiar with what those actually represent.  Also keep in mind that if all three filters exist, you are overwriting the value of `filteredSet1` and `filteredSet2` each time. That makes the first two `if` statements useless

Comment: @ChrisBarr - that was a mistake from my end, the expectation is to filter on result of the previous filtered results. I have updated the logic above.

Comment: Ok, yes that now makes more sense from a logic standpoint, however just `set1` and `set2` are meaningless. I see you have changed the filters to have meaningful names,  surely there must be better names or descriptions you could provide instead of just numbers "sets". Overall though your logic seems fine now. One or multiple filters can be applied if they exist, or unfiltered data can be returned if no filters exist. My only suggestion would be to just have `let filteredSet1 = result.set1` at the top instead of declaring it without a value and then only setting the value in the `else` branch.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will make that change. `set1` and `set2` are something that I have no control over, but in my code I have documented what they are and what data they contain.

Comment: ok, that makes sense in that case. You're working with what you've been given!